# Sphinx cannot create tables because the first table references another table, but I've been guaranteed that it works (tested in MariaDB and MySQL CE)

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

I get this error with MySQL CE:

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table 'application'
```

Story: I've just joined a company as a freelancer, and they've given me a Phabricator access. I've downloaded their API from its repo, and now I'm trying to set it up. First, create the tables with `migrate` then populate it with seeds. The framework is Phalcon, and the db data is under app/database. What could be wrong here? I can see that the first table references another table. My friend says there's no issue here. What could be wrong on my end?

Here's the first SQL migration file. There's over 20, but this one is making the trouble.

```
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('team');
        $table->addColumn('name', 'string', [
            'limit' => 255,
            'null'  => false
        ])
        ->addColumn('abbrev', 'string', [
            'limit' => 32,
            'null'  => false
        ])
        ->addColumn('stripe_account_id', 'string', [
            'null' => true
        ])
        ->addColumn('fee_rate', 'float', [
            'null' => false,
            'default' => 0.05
        ])
        ->addColumn('application_id', 'integer', [
            'limit' => 11,
        ])
        ->addIndex('application_id', ['name' => 'fk_team_application_idx'])
        ->addForeignKey('application_id', 'application', 'id',
            array('delete'=> 'CASCADE', 'update'=> 'CASCADE'))
        ->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help a great deal if you edit your question and show the code producing the error, including any SQL statement.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Done. There's over 18 files though, all creating different tables.

Comment: Does the application table exist? If so, you may need to include the DB name with the table name. Not sure, but you might try it,

Comment: You migght be better off having a script to create the tables without foreign keys, then once they are all created, add the foreign keys. You'll also need to keep track of those keys to determine the order in which you copy data into the tables.